# Jquery .on or .change method not working

Tags: jquery

I am hiding some input fields that are revealed when you enter a number in the numbFish question. I've tried both the .on and .change methods but the input fields don't show

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong?

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joepub/ru30w2a0/1/)

---

```
<head>
<script>
function catchData()     
{

    $('#submitbttn').click(function (e) 
    {
        if (parseInt($("#numbFish").val(), 10) === "" || parseInt($("#numbFish").val(), 10) === 0 || isNaN(parseInt($("#numbFish").val(), 10))) 
        {
            alert("Enter The Number Of Species");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        var numberOfSpec = $("#numbFish").val()

        $('#numbFish').on('input', function ()  <-- NOT EXECUTING
        {
            alert('Number of species: ' + numberOfSpec);
            if (parseInt($(this.value), 10) > 0) 
            {
                for (i = 0; i < $numberOfSpec; i++) 
                {
                    $('#' + numsp[i]).show();
                }
            }
        });

    });

}   

$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var numsp = ["spec1", "spec2", "spec3", "spec4", "spec5"];
    for (i = 0; i < numsp.length; i++) 
    {
        $('#' + numsp[i]).hide();
    }
    catchData();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form  method="POST" name="catchinfo" id="catchinfo">

<div class="container">  
    <div class='span4'>
        Number of the fish Species caught<br>
        <input id='numbFish' name="numbFish" type='text'/>
    </div>

</div><!-- end container-->

<div class="container">  
    <div class="row">  
        <div class="span4" id = 'spec1' name = 'spec1'>
            Enter name of the first fish Species<br>
        <input type='text'>
        </div>
        <div class="span4" id = 'spec2' name = 'spec2'>
            Enter name of the second fish Species<br>
            <input type='text'>
        </div>
        <div class="span4" id = 'spec3' name = 'spec3'>
            Enter name of the third fish Species<br>
            <input type='text'>
        </div>
        <div class="span4" id = 'spec4' name = 'spec4'>
            Enter name of the fourth fish Species<br>
            <input type='text'>
        </div>
        <div class="span4" id = 'spec5' name = 'spec5'>
            Enter name of the fifth fish Species<br>
            <input type='text'>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container-->


    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.js"></script>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At a quick glande: 1. You don't have a reference to `Jquery library` in your scripts.  2. You need to put your code *after* you load your libraries.

Comment: Do you want this to happen as they type or add a value, if so try using the keyboard events like `keyup`.  Also, you should cache your selector instead of retyping it every time.  `var numberOfSpec = $("#numbFish").val();  if (numberOfSpec) {}` The `if` would only execute if `numberOfSpec` is a truthy values like 1.  It would fail for null, undefined, 0, etc.

Comment: The event handler for the `#numbFish` input isn't added until you are inside the `submitbttn` click handler. So you don't have a handler on `#numbFish` until somebody clicks the `submitbttn`. Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/ru30w2a0/2/ it'll alert after the text box loses focus.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions!! I do have reference to JQ library in my original script but let it out along with other things to keep it bare bones.... Next time I will include the necessary libraries.  Thanks Matt, your comment pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, one issue is that you don't have a reference to your JQuery Library.  Add it at the beginning of your external references like so. Also, you are executing your JQuery before you have your libraries loaded.  You should place your scripts below the libraries.

```
<!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#numbFish").change(function () {
      alert($(this).val()); 
   });

   $("#submitbttn").click(function (e) {
      if (parseInt($("#numbFish").val(), 10) === "" || parseInt($("#numbFish").val(), 10) === 0 || isNaN(parseInt($("#numbFish").val(), 10))) 
        {
           alert("Enter The Number Of Species");
           e.preventDefault();
           return false;
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

As far as your JQuery, [Matt Burland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1250301/matt-burland) correctly pointed out that you are placing event handlers inside event handlers.  Your `numbFish` change event will only begin to work after the `submit click` event takes place.  To help get you going in the right direction, I've abstracted a couple of your functions and put them in the codeblock above, along with a [working example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imoshtokill/f4ryohhg/)

Comment: Thanks @silencedmessage and Matt Burland... I originally had the code in a separate function but changed it to what I shared... Got it working after reviewing what both of you wrote

Answer (score 0):

There are a pile of issues with what you've written but the key one is the `$('#numbFish').on('input'....` handler. This will not execute until the form is submitted, by which time I'm guessing it's too late. So you need to move that event handler outside of the submit method:

```
$('#submitbttn').click(function (e) 
    {
        if (parseInt($("#numbFish").val(), 10) === "" || parseInt($("#numbFish").val(), 10) === 0 || isNaN(parseInt($("#numbFish").val(), 10))) 
        {
            alert("Enter The Number Of Species");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }



});

    $('#numbFish').change(function () {
        alert('Number of species: ' + $(this).val());
        if (parseInt($(this).val(), 10) > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < $("#numbFish").val(); i++) {
                $('#' + numsp[i]).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

This should only deal with your `input` event. It's not trying to fix other concerns that seem to be piling up in your post's comments.